# An item with the same key has already been added error in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, entity

I'm upgrading an ASP.NET MVC 3 project to MVC 5 (VS 2017) and i have the below line of code

```
 IEnumerable<Country> countrydata = _db.Country.OrderBy(s => s.CountryName).ToList();
```

That line of code works fine in MVC 3 (in a .NET 4 project) but throws the below error in MVC 5 project targeting .NET 4.6.1, does anybody see why?

> An item with the same key has already been added

**UPDATE:**
After further testing, it seems like all such calls to the database will fail in MVC 5 / Entity Framework 6, because even the below line fails with the same error message.

```
IEnumerable<AuthenticationType> authenticationProvider = _db.AuthenticationType.OrderBy(n => uthenticationProvider).ToList();
```

@Christos, see the .edmx designer message i mention below

[image]

**Below is the stack trace**

> at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource) at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAttributeAssemblyLoader.LoadRelationshipTypes() at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAttributeAssemblyLoader.LoadTypesFromAssembly() at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAssemblyLoader.Load() at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAttributeAssemblyLoader.Load() at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, ObjectItemLoadingSessionData loadingData) at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, KnownAssembliesSet knownAssemblies, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage, Object& loaderCookie, Dictionary`2& typesInLoading, List`1& errors) at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.LoadAssemblyFromCache(ObjectItemCollection objectItemCollection, Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage) at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.ImplicitLoadAssemblyForType(Type type, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection) at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.ImplicitLoadAssemblyForType(Type type, Assembly callingAssembly) at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.GetTypeUsage(Type entityCLRType) at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.GetEntitySetForNameAndType(String entitySetName, Type entityCLRType, String exceptionParameterName) at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet[TEntity](String entitySetName) at SSAMapper.Models.SSAMapperEntities.get_Country() in D:\Projects\SSAMapper\Models\SSAMapper.Designer.cs:line 240 at SSAMapper.Models.AdminModel.GetCountries(Boolean status, Boolean userCountry, Boolean loadDeactivatedCountry) in D:\Projects\SSAMapper\Models\AdminModel.cs:line 1116

Comment: The error indicates a duplicate. Can you specify what is the content of _db_Country?

Comment: Duplicate was my first thought but i have checked the table and it has no duplicates. I have even applied a DISTINCT clause to the code but still i get the same error.

Comment: Can you describe how your table structure is alike and what your values are? Also, can you confirm that the call to ToList() makes the crash? You can try executing _db.Country.OrderBy(s => s.CountryName) only to see whether this works by itself.

Comment: I can confirm that the crash occurs even when i remove ToList(), just tried it.

Comment: Even if you do not assign a value and just call _db.Country.OrderBy(s => s.CountryName) ?

Comment: Yes even if i do not assign any value, i simply can not go past that line. After testing, it seems like all such calls to the database are failing (see another line of code in my original post)

Comment: @StackTrace Haven't you change anything in the EF models ? For instance, please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594236/entity-framework-an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-added-error-whe. Not the same case, but the same error message.

Comment: @Christos , actually when wanted to opened the  EF model designer for the first time after upgrading the project, the edmx designer displayed a message that "The Entity Model Designer is unable to display the file you requested" See screenshot in added to original message, in the screenshot i clicked "Modify".

Comment: Was this also an upgrade to Entity Framework 6 from an older version? Are you using code first or DB first? It sounds like maybe the key is incorrectly defined for the entities in question. But unless you have lazy loading turned off, the fact that you get the error even without calling `.ToList` makes me instead wonder if the `.edmx` has some other error in it - which might explain your designer error. Can you share the stack trace for the exception? You can also open the `.edmx` as XML and  see if anything with these entities looks off to you.

Comment: @xr280xr , Yes, this is an upgrade of Entity Framework from version 4 & i'm using DB first with lazy loading set to true. I have updated the original post with the full stack trace.

Comment: Ok. I'm still leaning towards an upgrade gone awry. It's using lazy loading, and you've removed `.ToList()` so the exception is thrown prior to any data access. We can see in the stack trace it's during creation of the `ObjectSet<TEntity>` and if I'm understanding it correctly, it looks to be when looking at relationships to make sure the assembly for their types are loaded. I would look at the `<NavigationProperty>`s  on the conceptual model in the .edmx and see if there appears to be any duplicates. It seems like it could also happen if you have duplicated model classes or...

Comment: if they are defined in more than one assembly in your bin (like if you renamed your project/target assembly but the original is still there). Here are a couple links that may be useful: [Upgrading to Entity Framework 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/what-is-new/upgrading-to-ef6) I would go through that and make sure I didn't miss anything. 
And also: [Same error with the source code involved shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206289/an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-added-just-in-release-mode/10212292)

Comment: @xr280xr, An upgrade gone awry is definitely the only explanation because in a brand new ASP.NET MVC 5 & Entity Framework 6 project, the same lines of code execute perfectly fine. I just had to delete the screwed .EDMX file and re-created it from the upgraded project then just made some code changes to make it compatible with Entity framework 6.

Comment: At this point, we can consider this issue as resolved.

Comment: Glad it's working! The best answer here would be comparing what you had with what you have now to identify the error, but I copied what I found as an answer to try to offer some help to anyone who comes across this. You don't have to mark it as _the_ answer since we haven't identified the exact cause.

Answer (score 0):

I'm leaning towards it being the upgrade to Entity Framework 6 gone awry. It's using lazy loading, and you've removed `.ToList()` so the exception is thrown prior to any data access. We can see in the stack trace it's during creation of the `ObjectSet<TEntity>` and if I'm understanding it correctly, it looks to be when looking at relationships to make sure the assembly for their types are loaded.

I would look at the `<NavigationProperty>`s on the conceptual model in the .edmx and see if there appears to be any duplicates. It seems like it could also happen if you have duplicated model classes in your project or if any of the model classes are defined in more than one assembly in your bin (like if you renamed your project/target assembly but the original dll is still there).

Here are a couple links that may be useful: [Upgrading to Entity Framework 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/what-is-new/upgrading-to-ef6) I would go through that and make sure nothing was missed. And [here was a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206289/an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-added-just-in-release-mode/10212292) with the same error with the source code involved shown.